# Importing deeply nested modules in Python

Tags: python, import, package, python-import, python-module

Consider the following case in Python 3.6:

```
basepackage
    |---__init__.py
    |---package
            |---__init__.py
            |---subpackage
                    |---__init__.py
                    |---module.py
```

**Important detail**: inside `basepackage.package.__init__.py` there's:

```
from basepackage.package.subpackage.module import AClass as AliasedClass
```

Now, let's say inside `basepackage.package.subpackage.module.py` we want to use:

`import basepackage.package.subpackage.module as aliased_module` **`[1]`**

The result is:

```
AttributeError: module 'basepackage' has no attribute 'package'
```

with a stack trace listing following culprit statements (in the below order):

```
from basepackage.package.subpackage.module import AClass as AliasedClass
import basepackage.package.subpackage.module as aliased_module
```

But if instead of `[1]` one'd like to use:

`from basepackage.package.subpackage import module as aliased_module` **`[2]`**

then everything works.

How is `[1]` so much different than `[2]` that the former results in an error and the latter not?

Answer (score 3):

For the first option (`import basepackage.package.subpackage.module as aliased_module`) to work, these conditions have to be met:

- `basepackage/__init__.py` has to contain a line similar to `from . import package` (the name `package` has to be defined inside this `basepackage/__init__.py` file)
- `basepackage/package/__init__.py` has to contain a line similar to `from . import subpackage`
- `basepackage/package/subpackage/__init__.py` has to contain a line similar to `from . import module`

Note: the import statements inside the `__init__.py` files can also be absolute instead of relative paths.

---

For the second option (`from basepackage.package.subpackage import module as aliased_module`), it is enough if there are empty `__init__.py` files at each level, as long as these `__init__.py` files exist.

Comment: Thx. Do you by any chance know some other (bit more comprehensible) resource than [this section in the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) to read up on this behavior?

Comment: @z33k Maybe this can help https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/

Comment: Is it somehow different with the standard library? Because I use `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` without problems (mind that `ElementTree` is a module) and I checked the source and `etree` package has an empty `__init__.py` and in `xml`'s one there are no imports and only `__all__` is defined.

Comment: @z33k Hm... maybe I was wrong? I don't know, I'm confused, I'm not sure about this case. In [this part of the already linked tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) it seems to give an example contrary to my explanation in the answer.