# Imported module does not import

Tags: python

I got 2 major issues, it was all fine when I had all scripts in one directory `TwitterAnalyzer`, but when I started cleaning up. Some problems occured.

I must import **TwitterApi** into `Analyzer` module. I have found solution, but I looks silly to me (`if __name__ == '__main__'`). Otherwise import will not work in parent module `_run_GUI_mode.py`

I also tried to make some `__init__.py` file, that imports both things, but it is not working 
`NameError: name 'TwitterApi' is not defined`
How to import correctly, that will allow me to run `Analyzer` independently.
I don't fully understand this topic, which may have answers: [Why does importing a python module not import nested modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303179/why-does-importing-a-python-module-not-import-nested-modules)

Should I move all scripts back to same directory? I will avoid additional work with path tracking to `tweets` directory. Analyzer is downloading tweets in background.

```
# My Project Tree
.TwitterAnalyzer
    |---LICENSE
    |---README.md
    |---TwitterAnalyzer
        |---Analyzer
            |---Analyzer.py
            |---Readme.md
            |---secret_token.txt
            |---TwitterApi.py
            |---__init__.py
        |---GUI
            |---create_gui_py.py
            |---GUI.py
            |---GUI_QT.ui
        |---tweets
        |---_run_GUI_mode.py
```

```
# Analyzer\TwitterAnalyzer.py
# Grzegorz Krug

if __name__ == '__main__':  # this is my solution, but I do not like it
    from TwitterApi import TwitterApi, TwitterLoginFailed 
else:
    from Analyzer.TwitterApi import TwitterApi, TwitterLoginFailed


class TwitterAnalyzer(TwitterApi):
    def __init__(self, autologin=True, log_ui=None):
...
```

```
# _run_GUI_mode.py
# Grzegorz Krug

from Analyzer.TwitterApi import TwitterApi, TwitterLoginFailed  # <-- This does not work anyway
from Analyzer.Analyzer import TwitterAnalyzer
from GUI.GUI import Ui_MainWindow

class TwitterAnalyzerGUI(TwitterAnalyzer, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, mainWindow):
...
```

```
# Analyzer/__init__.py
from TwitterApi import TwitterApi
from Analyzer import TwitterAnalyzer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `__init__.py` to TwitterAnalyzer directory

Comment: Try to add it in both TwitterAnalyzer direcotries (parent and child as the names are the same) and then ```from TwitterAnalyzer.TwitterAnalyzer.Analyzer.TwitterApi import TwitterApi```

Comment: you went 1x`TwitterAnalyzer` to high but it works, thanks

Comment: I have changed my mind, it works only pycharm, while runing scripts does not work at all :/